# Como indentar um arquivo yaml com o uso de expressão regular?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, yaml

```
PROD ="IND"
LOCATION ="NY"
LOLO ="abc"
yaml_content = """
    MAIN :
      PROD : {}
      LOCATION : {}
    EXTRA :
      LOLO : {}
    """.format(PROD, LOCATION, LOLO)
yaml_content = re.sub("\n\s", "\n", yaml_content.strip())

print yaml_content
```

Tenho como saída no print:

```
MAIN :
         PROD : IND
         LOCATION : NY
       EXTRA :
         LOLO : abc
```

Exitem espaço que não quero! O modo correto deveria ser:

```
MAIN :
  PROD : IND
  LOCATION : NY
EXTRA :
  LOLO : abc
```

Alguém sabe como devo reformular a re.sub(...)

Answer (score 1):

Repare que os espaços estão justamente dentro da tua *string*:

```
yaml_content = """
    MAIN :
      PROD : {}
      LOCATION : {}
    EXTRA :
      LOLO : {}
    """.format(PROD, LOCATION, LOLO)
```

E a maneira mais fácil de resolver isto seria produzir algo como:

```
yaml_content = (
    "MAIN:\n"+
        "\tPROD: {}\n" +
        "\tLOCATION: {}\n" +
    "EXTRA:\n" +
        "\tLOLO: {}\n").format(PROD, LOCATION, LOLO)
```

Não há a necessidade de usar *regex* para tal.

Claro, se o que você deseja é criar um arquivo YAML a partir de dados que já estejam armazenados em variáveis eu recomendo que você use o módulo [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/) pois bastará colocar os dados dentro de um dicionário e a linguagem fará o resto para você.